# ios FirebaseCoreDiagnostics 5.4.1 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppEnvironmentUtil"

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm try upgrade `firebase` from version 4.2.0 to version 5.4.1.
I'm getting this error, while building IOS:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppEnvironmentUtil", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRDiagnostics_b8d2083bbf595e32a15f4c92bf56379b.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULNetwork", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(FIRClearcutLogger_39f37e7cc81dbdcb1b22721b95a40297.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

any ideas how to fix that? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

fixed issue

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1585

Please download the latest version.

Comment: Thanks Karaage-Kun! you are wright! I updated Firebase 5.4.1 and build success!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to delete completely the derived data?

You can find the folder to delete under "Preference - Locations" of XCode:

[image]

Then delete it and try to rebuild the project.

Comment: thanks for reply me! i tried remove derived data but still getting same error!

Comment: I get the same issue. 
In my circumstances I don't use CocoaPods, seems that whatever I should be getting GULAppEnvironmentUtil and GULNetwork from is missing.

Comment: Hi Kerberos! I don't use CocoaPods, i add framework same Chris Conway.